# Simple Electromagnetics question

Tags: electromagnetic

Question)
The normal element of charge density of surface of conductor is ax + ay + az(sum of unit vectors).

What is charge density? The permittivity of electric field around surface of conductor is ε.

Answer)

En = √3

Ps = Dn = εEn = √3

Can anyone explain this? I have checked all pages of my study material, and I can't find basic law of this?

Comment: Charge density is not a vector, so what do you mean by "the normal element of charge density"?

Comment: Are the unit vectors \$\hat{a}_x, \dots\$ or \$\hat{x}, \dots\$ (where *a* is a scalar) ? If it is the former, the length of the vector is \$\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2}\$. I agree that the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Well, i have just translated it from what is written in not English. But i translated it word by word. 'Normal' is the same 'Normal' of 'Normal Vector'. I am sure you are not asking the meaning Normal.

Comment: Yes it is unit vector, ax => unit vector of x axis.

Comment: I think they are using the magnitude part of the vector to represent the charge density (coulomb/m^2) and the unit vector direction part of the vector to represent the surface orientation.

Comment: So length of the vector is*probably* the charge density (coulomb/m^2).

Comment: "What is charge density?" ... in terms of dimensional analysis, it is a quantity measured in Coulombs per meter^2 if the charge is constrained to a 2-dimensional surface, and Coulombs per meter^3 if the charge is distributed within a 3-dimensional volume, or I suppose Coulombs per meter if the charge is constrained to a 1-dimensional line. Context matters a great deal here. In layman's terms, it's a measure of the degree to which charge carriers are spatially packed into a space.

Comment: This appears to be just straightfroward geometry. If **thing** can be expressed as a vector, and if the cartesian elements of **thing** are ax+ay+az, or (a, a, a), then the magnitude of **thing** is sqrt(3).a, using the normal Euclidean sum. So the question is unusual in that charge density isn't usually expressed as a vector, and the answer seems to have silently made the subsitution a=1.